# sql group dates by 8 week period

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one table that I created with 52 weeks, based on Weekday = Sunday.
Now I need to aggregate these dates in groups of 8 weeks, but was not able to think of a logic to use in this case, I saw similar situations but none was useful.

[image]

I don't have much experience with SQL so I may have missed some obvious solutions.
any help will be appreciated

ps. The database is Snowflake

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, here is the sample of the code:

```
...
    , temp_datas as (
        select 
            week_end_dt2,
            row_number() over (order by week_end_dt2 desc) as row_num
        from calendar
    )
    , temp_groups as (
        select 
            week_end_dt2,
            ceil(row_num / 8.0) as group_num
        from temp_datas
    )
    select 
        calendar.*,
        temp_groups.group_num
    from calendar
    left join temp_groups on calendar.week_end_dt2 = temp_groups.week_end_dt2;
```